# $.ajax statusCode

Tags: ajax

I have a problem in my code . This is part of it:

```
 function checkIfAvailable(username){
 var url = "/checkAvail?user="+username;
 var ans =  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      context: document.body,
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 404!");
        },
        200: function() {
          console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 404!");
        }
      }
    });
         }
```

I think the response.status is 200, but I don't enter the '200' part.
So how can I print the response.status I'm getting?

Comment: did you try adding a `success` callback?

Comment: how can i do that? I'm a bit new at this..

Comment: you will always get `console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 404!");`

Comment: are u calling a php page if so `.php?user="+username;`

Comment: see code above (updated)

Comment: thank you, but is still not working..

Comment: I just figgured it out.. it's somthing else in my code that override's this code. thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 9):

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    var statusCode = jqXHR.status;
    var statusText = jqXHR.statusText;
}
```

[See jQuery API for more options...](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 6):

```
function checkIfAvailable(username) {
    var ans = $.ajax({
        url: "/checkAvail",
        type: "GET",
        data: "user=" + username,
        dataType: "html",//change it by the data type you get (XML...)
        context: document.body,
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 404!");
            },
            200: function() {
                console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 200!");
            }
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Message inside console.log("-1-1-1-1 WE GOT 404!") is same for both 404 and 200. change the message for 200 like console.log("Success.....")

Comment: ok. anyway, i dont get any printing... is there a way i can get a the ersponse.status that i'm getting?