# jQuery.ajax() returning code 404 on existing URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that checks the HTTP code returned by a given URL. After unsuccessful attempts, I tried this piece of code in jsfiddle and surprisingly got a 404:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"www.google.com",
   type: 'GET',
   statusCode: {
      200: function () {
         alert('200');
      },
      404: function () {
         alert('404');
      },
      500: function () {
         alert('500');
      }
  }
});
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
(Also, please note that this code doesn't work at all in my JavaScript file for some reason, but works in jsfiddle...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.ajax statusCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097776/ajax-statuscode)

Comment: Change url to `http://www.google.com` - urls are relative.

Comment: Did you look in your browser console on jsfiddle?  It gives this:  `GET https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: Of course, if you do use the correct url, you'll then get the CORS issue: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470433/jquery-cors-error